# Eliminate the yellow highlight that Chrome do in the textfiels on html forms

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, google-chrome, styling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop Chrome from yellowing my site's input boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175951/how-do-i-stop-chrome-from-yellowing-my-sites-input-boxes)

i have a web form that when i see from Chrome it makes a yellow highlight on the text fields and i dont like it. I eliminate the border highlight with **outline: none;** but when i go back to my form and Chrome autocomplete the fields it makes the fields background yellow, and that is not good for my theme. This is an example of the autocomplete that changes the background from my original transparent to yellow:

[alt text http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/2231/yellowmal.png](http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/2231/yellowmal.png)

What can i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no real good solution out there at the moment since this style is marked as `!important` by Chrome. A known workaround means to disable autocomplete like this:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
 <input type="text" name="fieldname" />
</form>
```

There are several issues raised in the chromium google code project where you could vote on but this issue seems to be a never ending story (first issue was started in 2008):

- [Auto-filled input text box yellow background highlight cannot be turned off!](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1334)
- [Auto-filled input text box yellow background highlight cannot be turned off!](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46543)

Answer (score 4):

Check out this similar question on StackOverflow: [Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background)

The short answer is that there is no way to do this.  Browser and user preferences and security concerns override site design.  Consider that your visitors with autofill enabled are probably used to seeing yellow in form fields, so the current behavior is consistent with their expectations.