# box-shadow on inputs in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, focus, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop Chrome from yellowing my site’s input boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175951/how-do-i-stop-chrome-from-yellowing-my-sites-input-boxes)

I've come across a little bug that I'm unable to solve, basically I have:

```
    input:focus {
        border: 1px solid #38a9f0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(56, 169, 240, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(56, 169, 240, 0.75);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(56, 169, 240, 0.75);
    }
```

to style the boxes when a user selects it, however, chrome already has a default on focus which is yellow, so along with the above it turns it to a very dark and ugly green. Is there any way to override chromes default colours?

Regards,
Karl

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175951/how-do-i-stop-chrome-from-yellowing-my-sites-input-boxes

Comment: Awesome thanks, outline: none; fixed it :) submit that as an answer please so I can mark it solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in [this SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175951/how-do-i-stop-chrome-from-yellowing-my-sites-input-boxes) you can simply use the following CSS to override the outline, but do make sure (as you said you would) that you replace it with some indication of focus.

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea, select { 
  outline: none;
}
```

You can simple use the `outline: none;` piece if that's all you need, that is simply the way to override all of the potential outlines.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting !important at the end of the line in CSS.  This should override the default. For instance: 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(56, 169, 240, 0.75) !important;