# How to change box-shadow to similar command in css?

Tags: css, safari, frontend

I have problem because shadow in my components doesnt work on safari.

I tried to change box-shadow to filter: drop-shadow() but this doesnt work in internet explorer 11.

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
```

Do you know some similar command that I can swap and show same effect as box-shadow?

Comment: You can see actual browser support & known issues for the box-shadow here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good link: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

```
.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow:    0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow:         0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
```

**Update:**
You can see the actual browser support and known issues here:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

**Update2:**
You can check this thread also - it may contain relevant info to you regarding the safari problem (color, sizes, etc.). The `0.12` may be a to small shadow for safari, according to the 1st answer.
[css box shadow property is not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953282/css-box-shadow-property-is-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: How to set shadows for many browsers that them don't duplicate themself? Eg ie, mozilla, chrome, safari on mac etc

Comment: What do you mean by "duplication"? The shadow is darker, or what happens? It shouldn't be duplicated - because each browser should have it's on rule from above. Maybe you can find this one useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127748/box-shadow-on-inputs-in-chrome

Comment: If in mozilla work box-shadow, and in my css there are box-shadow, and -moz-box-shadow, what will happen then?

Comment: It will first try to use the simple "box-shadow", if possible (I think). If the browser version is older (and "box-shadow" is not recognized in the given browser) it will use the -moz / -webkit alternative. Check this page to see what&where will work: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow