# auto complete attibute not working in HTML

Tags: html

I have input box with email address. It should not be auto complete but even after added autocomplete="off" in input box. Its showing auto complete values.

Comment: `autocomplete` is just a suggestion for the browser, try `autocomplete="nope"` - for more information see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: i tried autocomplete="nope" but no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop Chrome from yellowing my site's input boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175951/how-do-i-stop-chrome-from-yellowing-my-sites-input-boxes)

Answer (score 0):

it is probably found in chrome...but you can try

in form tag add `autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" autofill="off"`

and then add following code after form opens...

```
<input type="text" name="usernamefake" style="display:none;"> 
<input type="password" name="fakepassword" style="display:none;"> 

<!-- from here now your all input fields...below-->
```

If your problem doesn't get solve with above solution, *you can add one more hidden fake input field just above your actual email input field* and have a try...

**Update :**

you can try

```
<input type="text" name="email" readonly  onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) {
 this.removeAttribute('readonly');
 this.blur();    this.focus();  }" />
```

`this.blur(); this.focus();` is for mobile screens to show keyboard after readonly attribute is removed..by js

**EXAMPLE CODE :**

```css
div{
  padding:10px;
  margin:20px;
}
input {
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<form autocomplete="off">
  <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
  <input id="email" readonly type="email" onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) { this.removeAttribute('readonly');
     this.blur();    this.focus();  }" />
  <br/>
  <label for="pw">Password</label>
  <input id="pw" readonly type="password" onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) { this.removeAttribute('readonly');
    this.blur();    this.focus();  }" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>

</div>
```